# error: 'IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY' was not declared in this scop

Tags: c++, winapi, deviceiocontrol

I've included `winioctl.h` and there is no `#define` for `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` in that file !! http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/storage/k307_8z3m.htm Says Its in `ntddstor.h` But I cannot find any `ntddstor.h`  on my Windows XP. 
However[`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  mentions its supposed to work with Windows XP (I dont need > Vista Specifc Queries) and It mentions to include `winioctl.h` only ! (I am not using Visual C++, I an using Qt with MinGW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used MinGW to compile these kind of programs. It may not be so easy to find, because frankly, the MinGW site is quite a mess, but they provide a lot of DDK header with no pain. Then I simply copy/paste the structs and defines I need and that I cannot find in the SDK headers. The macros, I define them conditionally, to avoid conflicts, just in case.

For example, your IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY is in mingw/include/ddk/ntddstor.h

```
#define IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY \
  CTL_CODE(IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE, 0x0500, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

So I add in my projects:

```
#ifndef IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY
    #define IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY \
      CTL_CODE(IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE, 0x0500, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
#endif
```

That's particularly useful if you intend to publish your code, as most people don't have the DDK headers, and they insist on using VisualStudio instead of MinGW.

Comment: Yah I just found the Same Solution tonight. in a file [`diskid32.cpp`](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.cpp)

Comment: However What about putting `mingw/include/ddk` in include Path ?

Comment: @NeelBasu I think that they are intended to be included as `#include <ddk/ntddstor.h>`. No need to add the include path, assuming the `mingw/include` is already there.

Answer (score 1):

I see IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY definition in WinIoCtl.h, and it compiles without any #ifdef conditions. What is your version of this file, how is it installed? I use WinIoCtl.h from VC++ 2010. Maybe you need to install Windows SDK.

Possibly your WinIoCtl.h comes from old Visual Studio or SDK. Install newest Visual Studio version, if this is impossible - install latest Microsoft Windows SDK and ensure that its include directory is listed first in your compiler.

Comment: Then Why I am getting all other defines and structures ?